# Should skinny guys go to gym for getting better body?

Tags: bodybuilding, gym

Heyy!

I am 16, 5'7" and skinny. I have been trying a lot to gain some body like a normal person then I can go to gym and start building muscle. Now I am thinking to go to gym to build muscle as well as gain weight. I am confused on something, some people says that if I go to gym and start building muscle then I won't get more height, will stay same height, I cannot gain weight and more blah blah blah.
Also, some people says "eat big and get big also eat quality not quantity" but I have trying this stuff since long time ago but no result yet :/ :(

Now I'd like to know it clearly from big dude or hard-gainer :p that, does gym impact on height and can I gain weight by gym? also know me, should I go to gym?
also hoping for some recommendation from big-dude/hard-gainer :)

Cheers!

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally false, lifting won't affect your height. That's what genes are for. Building muscle mass however will definitely help you gain weight; you will simply need to eat a lot.

If you've tried eating a lot before and it didn't work, it means you didn't eat enough. Get about 1 gram of protein or more per pound of body weight and find yourself a good beginner program based around the big lifts to bring up some strength; you'll gain weight.

Comment: great, can you give me some recommend which could help me

Comment: I would definitely recommend the 5*5 strong-lifts program, with a healthy surplus of calories, you'll be stronger in no time: http://stronglifts.com/5x5/

Answer (score 1):

If your target is to just gain weight you need not hit gym. It would be advisable if you could change your diet plan. Rate of gaining or losing weight varies person to person. Body metabolism governs body structure. Your body is in growing state. Allow it grow and maintain healthy diet and you will gain weight gradually.